# JS and CSS Files in MERN Stack (with Typescript) DigitalOcean Showing HTML files instead

Tags: typescript, deployment, build, digital-ocean, mern

First, in the console I get this

[image]

Have built the app with ubuntu, nginx so far... no firewall set up yet, etc.
First time deploying a MERN stack, first time using DigitalOcean.

Steps I'm taking to get app up and running:

1. First I'm running npm run build in the server, to compile tsx to js.
2. Then I'm running npm run build in the client.
3. I move the client's build folder to the server's build folder, renaming it static.
4. In the server folder, i run pm2 start build/index.js, so it's pointing to build/static/index.html.

Following image is the result when i run the droplet ip address.

[image]

The js/main.js file is the same.

Following is my index.ts file.

```
import express from 'express'
import userRoutes from './routes/user-routes'
import membershipRoutes from './routes/membership-routes'
import memberPlanRoutes from './routes/plan-routes'
import passwordRoutes from './routes/password-routes'
import memberExtendRoutes from './routes/extend-routes'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()

dotenv.config()

app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }))
app.use(express.static('static'))
app.use(cors())
app.enable('trust proxy')

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  )
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE')
  next()
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static/index.html'))
})


app.use('/api/membership/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: '*/*' }))
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)
app.use('/api/membership', membershipRoutes)
app.use('/api/plan', memberPlanRoutes)
app.use('/api/password', passwordRoutes)
app.use('/api/extend', memberExtendRoutes)

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL as string).then(() => {
  console.log('connected to mongodb')
})


app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(`Your server is ready on port 8080!`)
})
```

I've tried to replace the app.get('*') to ('/') as well as other variations and either got same results or no static folder at all.

I also ran across the following comment but don't understand how to implement it.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some good soul on DigitalOcean replied with this code, and now it works!

```html
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'));
});
```